# How to order a string with a number in it properly

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have the following items:

```
- Orange Is the New Black, Season 1, Ep. 1 -- I Wasn't Ready
- Orange Is the New Black, Season 1, Ep. 10 -- Bora Bora Bora
- Orange Is the New Black, Season 1, Ep. 2 -- Tit Punch
```

Currently, now I'm doing `SELECT title FROM table ORDER BY title`.

How would I order this properly in mysql? That is, so the result is:

```
- Orange Is the New Black, Season 1, Ep. 1 -- I Wasn't Ready
- Orange Is the New Black, Season 1, Ep. 2 -- Tit Punch
- Orange Is the New Black, Season 1, Ep. 10 -- Bora Bora Bora
```

Comment: Is the format fixed? Meaning do you **always** have `- <something>, Season <N>`, Ep. <N>`

Comment: The quick answer is make sure that season and episode numbers are zero-padded or store titles parsed into separate columns. If the the title format is fixed you can do some string manipulation magic, but it will cause a fullscan each time you query your data

Answer (score 2):

So long as the format of the `title` sting is not changed,
you can use `substring_index`, and `cast` in `order by` clause to sort.

```
select * from table
order by
cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX( title, ', Ep. ', -1 ) as decimal);
```

Comment: @JohnRuddell: Your SQL Fiddle example has syntax errors

Comment: yea sorry thats because i changed it.. this is with your example. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02696/11 ------ basically i did it with yours, then with someone else's post and it saved it as theirs.

Comment: Yea. That one works. I tested before posting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge you can’t do this way. You have 2 options one is creating separate columns for title `Ex: name, season, Ep Number,` etc. … , Other one is using split function but it is not a good solution.

Comment: it can be done. if you aren't sure then probably shouldn't post something. see answers for answer of how to do it.

Comment: It seems OP has this value generated from a concatenation operation on related table fields. Let us hope he knows what is normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is make sure that season and episode numbers are zero-padded or store titles parsed into separate columns. If the the title format is fixed you can do some string manipulation magic, but it will cause a fullscan each time you query your data

---

Now if the format is fixed and you up to string manipulation you can do

```sql
SELECT title
  FROM table1
 ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, 'Ep. ', 1), 
          1 * SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, 'Ep.', -1), '--', 1)
```

*That's assuming that the number of seasons is always less than 10.*

Output:

```
|                                                         TITLE |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| - Orange Is the New Black, Season 1, Ep. 1 -- I Wasn't Ready  |
| - Orange Is the New Black, Season 1, Ep. 2 -- Tit Punch       |
| - Orange Is the New Black, Season 1, Ep. 10 -- Bora Bora Bora |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2358c/5)** demo